# Logistic Regression Using Zelig [R]

Tags: r, r-zelig

I'm running a logit model using the zelig package in R:

```
z.out <- zelig(trade961a ~ age962 + education962 + personal962 + economy962 + partisan962 + employment962 + union962 + home962 + market962 + race962 + income962, data=data96, model="logit")
```

The dependent variable, trade961a, is a dichotomous factor variable. All other variables are numeric.

I am interested in personal962, which is:

```
> str(personal962)
 num [1:1714] 3 3 1 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 ...
```

so I run the following to simulate the probability of supporting international trade when personal962 is 1 (better):

```
x.out <- setx(z.out, personal962=1)
```

I get the following error message:

```
#Error in dta[complete.cases(mf), names(dta) %in% vars, drop = FALSE] :
#  incorrect number of dimensions
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might not be doing anything wrong. There's a record on the Zelig mailing list archive of someone having this same problem, and eventually solving it simply by reinstalling Zelig and all the packages it depends on ([see here](http://lists.hmdc.harvard.edu/lists/zelig/2010_02/msg00006.html)).